# combine array values in sub array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I retrieve articles information from a mysql database I got an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 3
            [CategoryName] => Test Category
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 8
            [ArticleID] => 2
            [ArticleCatgories] => 9,4,3
            [ArticleTitle] => vxcvxcvx
            [ArticleBody] => xcvxcvxcvxcv
            [InGroup] => 0
            [GroupID] => 0
            [Published] => 1
            [PublishTime] => 
            [TermID] => 11
            [TermSlug] => xcvxcvxcv
            [RelatedID] => 2
            [TermType] => article
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 4
            [CategoryName] => Test Image
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 4
            [ArticleID] => 2
            [ArticleCatgories] => 9,4,3
            [ArticleTitle] => vxcvxcvx
            [ArticleBody] => xcvxcvxcvxcv
            [InGroup] => 0
            [GroupID] => 0
            [Published] => 1
            [PublishTime] => 
            [TermID] => 11
            [TermSlug] => xcvxcvxcv
            [RelatedID] => 2
            [TermType] => article
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 9
            [CategoryName] => Test Images
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 7
            [sort] => 2
            [ArticleID] => 2
            [ArticleCatgories] => 9,4,3
            [ArticleTitle] => vxcvxcvx
            [ArticleBody] => xcvxcvxcvxcv
            [InGroup] => 0
            [GroupID] => 0
            [Published] => 1
            [PublishTime] => 
            [TermID] => 11
            [TermSlug] => xcvxcvxcv
            [RelatedID] => 2
            [TermType] => article
        )
}
```

And because the article is in more than one category, it retrieve the article information more than once.
What I need to do is to combine the category names into a sub array if they have the same ArticleID so the result become like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CategoryName] => array('Test Category','Test Image','Test Images');
            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 8
            [ArticleID] => 2
            [ArticleCatgories] => 9,4,3
            [ArticleTitle] => vxcvxcvx
            [ArticleBody] => xcvxcvxcvxcv
            [InGroup] => 0
            [GroupID] => 0
            [Published] => 1
            [PublishTime] => 
            [TermID] => 11
            [TermSlug] => xcvxcvxcv
            [RelatedID] => 2
            [TermType] => article
        )
}
```

Comment: Mysql has Group Concat. You will be much faster letting MySQL handle that instead of looping a larger result-set later in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new array using `ArticleID` as the keys:

```
$final = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $id = $row['ArticleID'];
    if (isset($final[$id])) {
        // we've already seen this article
        // append to categoryname array
        $final[$id]['CategoryName'][] = $row['CategoryName'];
    } else {
        // this is the first article occurrence
        // turn categoryname into array first
        $row['CategoryName'] = array($row['CategoryName']);
        $final[$id] = $row;
    }
}

print_r($final);
```

Output based on your question:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [CategoryID] => 3
            [CategoryName] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Test Category
                    [1] => Test Image
                    [2] => Test Images
                )

            [Parent] => 0
            [Thumb] => 0
            [sort] => 8
            [ArticleID] => 2
            [ArticleCatgories] => 9,4,3
            [ArticleTitle] => vxcvxcvx
            [ArticleBody] => xcvxcvxcvxcv
            [InGroup] => 0
            [GroupID] => 0
            [Published] => 1
            [PublishTime] =>
            [TermID] => 11
            [TermSlug] => xcvxcvxcv
            [RelatedID] => 2
            [TermType] => article
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce)

```
$array = Array(
    "0" => Array("CategoryID" => 3,"CategoryName" => "Test Category","Parent" => 0,"Thumb" => 0,"sort" => 8,"ArticleID" => 2,"ArticleCatgories" => "9,4,3","ArticleTitle" => "vxcvxcvx","ArticleBody" => "xcvxcvxcvxcv","InGroup" => 0,"GroupID" => 0,"Published" => 1,"PublishTime" => null,"TermID" => 11,"TermSlug" => "xcvxcvxcv","RelatedID" => 2,"TermType" => "article"),
    "1" => Array("CategoryID" => 4,"CategoryName" => "Test Image","Parent" => 0,"Thumb" => 0,"sort" => 4,"ArticleID" => 3,"ArticleCatgories" => "9,4,3","ArticleTitle" => "vxcvxcvx","ArticleBody" => "xcvxcvxcvxcv","InGroup" => 0,"GroupID" => 0,"Published" => 1,"PublishTime" => null,"TermID" => 11,"TermSlug" => "xcvxcvxcv","RelatedID" => 2,"TermType" => "article"),
    "2" => Array("CategoryID" => 9,"CategoryName" => "Test Images","Parent" => 0,"Thumb" => 7,"sort" => 2,"ArticleID" => 2,"ArticleCatgories" => "9,4,3","ArticleTitle" => "vxcvxcvx","ArticleBody" => "xcvxcvxcvxcv","InGroup" => 0,"GroupID" => 0,"Published" => 1,"PublishTime" => null,"TermID" => 11,"TermSlug" => "xcvxcvxcv","RelatedID" => 2,"TermType" => "article"),
    "3" => Array("CategoryID" => 4,"CategoryName" => "Test A","Parent" => 0,"Thumb" => 0,"sort" => 4,"ArticleID" => 3,"ArticleCatgories" => "9,4,3","ArticleTitle" => "vxcvxcvx","ArticleBody" => "xcvxcvxcvxcv","InGroup" => 0,"GroupID" => 0,"Published" => 1,"PublishTime" => null,"TermID" => 11,"TermSlug" => "xcvxcvxcv","RelatedID" => 2,"TermType" => "article"),
    "4" => Array("CategoryID" => 9,"CategoryName" => "Test B","Parent" => 0,"Thumb" => 7,"sort" => 2,"ArticleID" => 2,"ArticleCatgories" => "9,4,3","ArticleTitle" => "vxcvxcvx","ArticleBody" => "xcvxcvxcvxcv","InGroup" => 0,"GroupID" => 0,"Published" => 1,"PublishTime" => null,"TermID" => 11,"TermSlug" => "xcvxcvxcv","RelatedID" => 2,"TermType" => "article")
);

$array = array_reduce($array, function ($a, $b) {
    is_null($a) ? $a = array() : null;
    if (!isset($a[$b['ArticleID']])) {
        $a[$b['ArticleID']] = $b ;
        $a[$b['ArticleID']]['CategoryName'] = array($b['CategoryName']);
    } else {
        $a[$b['ArticleID']]['CategoryName'][] = $b['CategoryName'];
    }
    return $a;
});

var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  2 => 
    array
      'CategoryID' => int 3
      'CategoryName' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Test Category' (length=13)
          1 => string 'Test Images' (length=11)
          2 => string 'Test B' (length=6)
      'Parent' => int 0
      'Thumb' => int 0
      'sort' => int 8
      'ArticleID' => int 2
      'ArticleCatgories' => string '9,4,3' (length=5)
      'ArticleTitle' => string 'vxcvxcvx' (length=8)
      'ArticleBody' => string 'xcvxcvxcvxcv' (length=12)
      'InGroup' => int 0
      'GroupID' => int 0
      'Published' => int 1
      'PublishTime' => null
      'TermID' => int 11
      'TermSlug' => string 'xcvxcvxcv' (length=9)
      'RelatedID' => int 2
      'TermType' => string 'article' (length=7)
  3 => 
    array
      'CategoryID' => int 4
      'CategoryName' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Test Image' (length=10)
          1 => string 'Test A' (length=6)
      'Parent' => int 0
      'Thumb' => int 0
      'sort' => int 4
      'ArticleID' => int 3
      'ArticleCatgories' => string '9,4,3' (length=5)
      'ArticleTitle' => string 'vxcvxcvx' (length=8)
      'ArticleBody' => string 'xcvxcvxcvxcv' (length=12)
      'InGroup' => int 0
      'GroupID' => int 0
      'Published' => int 1
      'PublishTime' => null
      'TermID' => int 11
      'TermSlug' => string 'xcvxcvxcv' (length=9)
      'RelatedID' => int 2
      'TermType' => string 'article' (length=7)
```

Comment: the array_reduce example work and but it just return the array and my sql query return multi array and multi Article Ids not only 1

Comment: @Baba the abuse of the ternary is not necessary https://3v4l.org/GKiZ1 ... or at least it is not necessary anymore (I don't know if `null` used to be the default accumulator back in the day).

Answer (score -1):

This is really a quick and dirty way of doing it but this is how it goes:

`$orig` is the original array posed in the question.

You basically iter the array and get all the categories and add them to `$keys`. Now assuming that all the other keys and values are same for the original array (except that category of course), you can just pick any element from that array and call it your `$final` array.

After that, you simply replace the category values with the array of the combined categories.

```
$orig = array();

$final = array();
$keys = array();

foreach($orig as $i)
{
    $keys[] = $i['CategoryName'];
}

$final = $orig[0];
$final['CategoryName'] = $keys;
```

Comment: this on is return the first result only not showing all results